# Drupal and integration of paypal express checkout

Tags: php, drupal, paypal, drupal-7

I am new to Drupal. I have a book-publisher website, which is not an onlineshop but that displays numerous Books. They now want to integrate a a pre-order button for one specific book. I figured out the best way and quickest way to do it is to use paypal express checkout. However, the paypal express checkout module just works with Drupal commerce, which is not installed, and I am not sure if it would be viable with all the book items they already have. What would be the best way to integrate paypal express checkout just for that one specific book ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement anything in Drupal is to either use an existing contrib module or to [create a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7).

In addition to the [Commerce Paypal Express Checkout](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal_ec) (which I guess is the one mentionned in the question), which require [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/Commerce) to be used, you could also use the [PayPal for Payment](https://www.drupal.org/project/paypal_payment) module, which only require the simpler [Payment](https://www.drupal.org/project/payment) module.

Out of the box, neither solution will provide a complete working solution.Commerce require lots of configuration. The Payment Form Field module bundle with Payment may be enough for you needs and is easy to configure (add a field to a Content type). But more complexe needs usually require a custom module build with Payment API.

A third option is off-course to implement the PayPal payment yourself, in a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [Getting Started With Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) and have a look at the section titled "Implementing the Simplest Express Checkout Integration". However, this is not the simplest way. A standard PayPal "Buy Now" button would be the simplest way. Go to [Single-Item Payments – Buy Now Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buynow_buttons/) to read how to do it.

Comment: Thank you Kevin, I will have a look at it. My questions rather also goes to as it would be possible to integrate paypal with "naked" code, thus not relying on drupal modules.